# Django: Annotating age from date_of_birth

Tags: django, annotate

I have a date of birth (**dob**) DateField in my Django Model (**Author**). I tried to annotate **age** parameter. I searched for many possible ways to do it and each procedure generated some kind of error.

Here I tried in python console first to make sure that the expression would be a valid one:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> (datetime.now() - datetime(2000,1,1)).days #output: 7506
```

First Try:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> authors = Author.objects.annotate(age = (datetime.now()-F('dob')).days) #no-error here
>>> print(authors) # Exception thrown here

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 324, in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1305, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 70, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 291, in convert_datefield_value
    value = parse_date(value)
  File "/home/puru/Documents/Python/django/prac1/django-master/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-3.2-py3.7.egg/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 75, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Second time I used ExpressionWrapper to define that output type will be DateTimeField

```
>>> from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper
>>> authors = Author.objects.annotate(age = ExpressionWrapper(timezone.now() - F('dob'), output_field=DateTimeField()).days)

AttributeError: 'ExpressionWrapper' object has no attribute 'days'
```

I have also tried the RawSQL. I am using Sqlite database here. so *date('now')* would provide me current date.

```
>>> from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
>>> authors = Author.objects.annotate(age=RawSQL("date('now')-dob"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'
```

So is there any way, I could solve the issue?

Comment: Can you add the `Author` model to your question, just the `dob` field would probably do

Comment: Here you go @IainShelvington  `dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth')`

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there, the issue was the **`output_field`** value. It should be **`DurationField`** instead of `DateTimeField`

```
age_expr = ExpressionWrapper(timezone.now() - F('dob'), output_field=DateTimeField())
queryset = Author.objects.annotate(age=age_expr)
```

**NOTE:** You can't use **`.days`** along with `ExpressionWrapper` since the annotate operation performs in the DB level.

---

To calculate the age, you may need to use the [**`.total_seconds()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method

```
print(queryset[0].age.total_seconds() / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25)
```

Comment: Awesome! But the years are defined by `datetime.timedelta(microseconds=21)` i.e. in microseconds.

Comment: By using `DurationField`, Django converts the DB results into Python's [**`timedelta`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects, which does not have a **`.year`** attribute.

Comment: So Isn't there a way I could get months and days an particular author have completed? So I need to consider microseconds as year in my code?

Comment: logically how could a 1999 A.D. person could be 21 microseconds. Shouldn't it show like `datetime.timedelta(days=7663)` ?

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(microseconds=21)` is only the **`__str__`** representation of the class. Hav you used **`.total_seconds()`**?

Comment: When I use `author[0].age.total_seconds()` , The result is **2.1e-05**

Comment: as the name suggests, it will be in seconds, you need to do the math.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer was helpful!! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218181/discussion-between-pax-and-arakkal-abu).

Answer (score 1):

*I am aware the OP is about **SQLite**, though the below snippet might help others seeking to achieve the same with **PostgreSQL**.*

Google search for `django annotate age`  returns this post as the first result.

---

**PostgreSQL** specific.

Postgres has an [`age` function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-age/) which can be combined with [`date_part` function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-date_part/) to calculate the age in years.

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, IntegerField, Value
from django.utils import timezone

authors = Author.objects.annotate(
    age=Func(
        Value("year"),
        Func(Value(timezone.now().date()), F("dob"), function="age"),
        function="date_part",
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose following solution:

```py
self.get_queryset().annotate(
  age=ExpressionWrapper(
    date.today().year - ExtractYear('dob')
    - Case(
      When(Q(dob__month__gt=date.today().month), then=Value(1)),
      When(Q(dob__month=date.today().month) & Q(dob__day__gt=date.today().day), then=Value(1)),
      default=Value(0)
      ), output_field=models.IntegerField()))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Empty string or list params worked for the RawSQL command.

`authors = Author.objects.annotate(age=RawSQL("date('now')-dob", params=""))`